Is it possible to make algorithm handle object’s members generically?
I still not sure that the title is quite correct, since I don’t know the answer, so any suggestions to improve it are welcome.
I need a way to compute extents (min and max values) for some container of numbers while these containers could contain types which don't define operator< explicitly; so I need a way to consider their interval members as PoD to compare.
I have a template with handles extents of some value, let’s say:
template <typename T>
struct extents {
    // Initialized this "strange" way for further search min/max in containers
    T   min = std::numeric_limits<T>::max(),
        max = std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest();

    void update(T value) {
        min = std::min(min, value);
        max = std::max(max, value);
    }

    T midpoint() const {
        return std::midpoint(min, max);
    }
};

It works just fine with PoD types like here:
    float a[] = { 1.0f, 5.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };

    extents<float> ext;

    for (auto v : a) {
        ext.update(v);
    }

(Well, I know std::minmax could be used here, sometimes it couldn’t).
With "extents" here I mean smallest and largest values of the container of elements.
When in comes to compound types I have to define operator< which is not trivial (like for my example with vectors). I definitely need something different than users (mathematicians, game developers, etc.) will expect here. I need to check if any of components is smaller than its counterpart in another compound value, so I don’t want and most often just can’t define operator< here. I can introduce separate methods, but again this is not always possible. Even if I do this, this would inflict performance impact, since I would be forced to handle vec2 as an object at most steps while I need member values only.
Is there a way to make code like here work?
    vec2 va[] = { {1.0f, 3.0f}, {5.0f, 2.0f} , {1.0f, 3.0f} };

    extents<vec2> vext;

    for (auto v : va) {
        vext.update(v);  // This won't compile because of reasons in text of the question
    }

I can do all this manually, the question is, can I somehow wrap this in extents class and its usage so that this is done automatically for any type compound from PoD types keeping the treatment of members to my responsibility or allowing me to control which members to take?
I would like to come with the solution like:
    vec2 va[] = { {1.0f, 3.0f}, {5.0f, 2.0f} , {1.0f, 3.0f} };

    extents<vec2> vext(&vec2::x, &vec2::y);

    for (auto v : va) {
        vext.update(v);
    }

which would mean “consider every member independently as a SOA (structure or arrays) or a channel when you compare them and as single unit AOS (array of structures) when you do assignment”.
In other words, I want my code to do the same as:
    vec2 va[] = { {1.0f, 3.0f}, {5.0f, 2.0f} , {1.0f, 3.0f} };

    extents<vec2>;

    for (auto v : va) {
        v.x.min = std::min(v.x.min,v);
        v.y.min = std::min(v.y.min,v);
        v.x.max = std::max(v.x.max,v);
        v.y.max = std::max(v.y.max,v);
    }

but without this mess of x,y,min/max in four lines where one update should be sufficient.
I assume it should work in a way
std::ranges::sort(va, std::less<>{}, &vec2::x);

works. I just need a way to specify the member to the update algorithm. The context seems to be very close: I need some algorithm to work based on some internal member.
The demo

I need to check if any of components is smaller than its counterpart in another compound value this is not clear, how would that work for vec2 ?

If i got this correctly then you need either c++26 reflection or something like boost pfr to loop over the struct elements.

I don't think you are clear about what you want. Are you establishing an ordered sequence and want to find median? Then nth_element is your friend. and you need to define the order. But your first example shows that you simply want midpoint between min and max, in which case you need to define what min and max mean for the objects you want to use it with. If you want to use midpoint supplying compound types and want the algorithm to use only members, then either supply a lambda or a filter to the algorithm.

@AhmedAEK, I was sure that it it obvious from the name of the "extent" type, sorry if not. I've updated the question. I need the smallest and largest (min/max) values of some container. For vec2 that would work component-wize as it is expected. If vec2::x of one object is smaller than others, it is stored in extents as the smallest. I need the same as I have for float.

@AhmedAEK, I've updated the code (see the last code snippet) which I want to replace with one update call for any further types to come.

@Gene, seems that you are totally lost in my question. Where do you see anything about ordered sequence? I just want to find extents of the values. I want to know max and min values for any type compound of PoD types like in my examples.

It sounds like what you want (for vectors at least) is component-wise vector min/max functions.

@ChrisDodd, exactly. This is what I mentioned in the question with "Even if I do this, this would inflict performance impact, since I would be forced to handle vec2 as an object at most steps while I need member values only." and the text above it. It is pretty clear how to do this manually, providing functions, etc. The question is how to do this "generically" or "automatically. How to tell the compiler "please compare these fields and use their values for min/max", not objects or their methods" so that could be used to any new type transparently without modifications and code growth.

@ChrisDodd, I've updated the question with the latest section. I feel that solution could be similar to std::ranges::sort(va, std::less<>{}, &vec2::x);. I just need a way to specify the member the the 'update' method. Is there any significant difference that could prevent it?

Your code handles a single value, to make it handle a struct with many values you need to use a lot of variadic templates, this is possible in C++17 with fold expressions and std::apply, older C++ versions will have to do a lot more tricks.
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T, typename...Getters>
struct extents {
    std::tuple<Getters...> getters;

    T   min;
    T   max;
    extents(Getters&&...g)
        : getters{ std::move(g)... } {
        std::apply([&](auto&&...f) {
            ((std::invoke(f,min) = std::numeric_limits<std::decay_t<decltype(std::invoke(f,std::declval<T>()))>>::max()), ...);
            ((std::invoke(f,max) = std::numeric_limits<std::decay_t<decltype(std::invoke(f,std::declval<T>()))>>::lowest()), ...);
            }, getters);
    }

    void update(const T& value) {
        std::apply([&](auto&&...f)
            {
                ((std::invoke(f,min) = std::min(std::invoke(f, min), std::invoke(f,value)),
                 (std::invoke(f,max) = std::max(std::invoke(f,max), std::invoke(f,value)))), ...);
            }, getters);
    }

    T midpoint() const {
        T t;
        std::apply([&](auto&&...f)
            {
                ((std::invoke(f,t) = (std::invoke(f,min) + std::invoke(f,max)) / 2), ...);
            }, getters);
        return t;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename...Getters>
auto make_extents(Getters&&...g) -> extents<T, Getters...>
{
    return extents<T, Getters...>{std::forward<Getters>(g)...};
}

struct vec2 {
    float x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f;
};

int main()
{
    vec2 va[] = { {1.0f, 3.0f}, {5.0f, 2.0f} , {1.0f, 3.0f} };

    auto vext = make_extents<vec2>(&vec2::x, &vec2::y);

    for (auto v : va) {
        vext.update(v);
    }

    std::cout << vext.midpoint().x << '\n';
    std::cout << vext.midpoint().y << '\n';
}

godbolt demo
note that you need T to be default constructible, and you need to specify accessor functions (&vec::x, &vec::y), a more generic code is possible with either C++26 reflection or C++14 boost pfr, (in which case extents will not be templated on Getters and instead uses boost::pfr::get as getters)

PFR version

Thank you so much for the solution. To be honest, if hurts, of course. I mean it shows that for my particular case in brings extra complexity to the project although does exactly what I asked about. This mostly related to the extents class which has many methods in my case and reworking and debugging it could be expensive. Let's wait for couple of days before accepting your answer in hope of simpler solutions (just in case somebody will come with a such), although I see now that it is next to impossible.

One question about the make_extents template. Why std::sort doesn't need it? Is it because we need variable number of arguments or because std::sort hides the same in some way in its implementation? My concern in client API where the simple extents object is replaced with the wrapper which from the first glance even hard to say (for a developer/client/user) what is it.

@Caleth, thank you for the PFR version. It helps to wait for C++26 reflection implementation (if I got correctly that in C++26 we will be able to do the same code without boost).

@DamirTenishev std::sort is already a function, it is equivalent to make_extents, which is used to bypas CTAD being an all-or-none, you cannot have the compiler deduce Getters if you call its constructor directly .... unless you use a function, this is a limitation in CTAD.

@AhmedAEK, thank you, I get it. I will look into std::sort implementation to find it. I have to look more carefully here. And thank you again for your implementation, only after reading your code and playing with it in attempts to simplify the solution, I really understood how deep the problem I wanted to solve is. Now I see that despite it is simple at first glance, it is hard call for compiling language.

@DamirTenishev make_extents deduces the types of Getters... from it's arguments, with a supplied T. You don't need it, as you could also write extents<vec2, decltype(&vec2::x), decltype(&vec2::y)> vext(&vec2::x, &vec2::y);, but it makes it nicer.
